# Can Finch play sounds from in memory NSData?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, nsdata, finch

Can the Finch library play sounds from NSData sources so that things recorded within the app using AVAudioRecorder can then be played back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The [`FISound`](https://github.com/zoul/Finch/blob/master/Finch/FISound.h) class has an initializer that takes an [`FISample`](https://github.com/zoul/Finch/blob/master/Decoder/FISample.h), which is just a simple wrapper around `NSData`. That means you can stuff your data into an `FISample` instance, fill in the audio metadata and use the sample to create an `FISound`.

Comment: It should be pretty obvious. What did you try, what didn’t work?

Comment: I see now that there is an NSData property on FISample and so I don't even need to go through the FIDecoder. I was thinking we had to use the FIDecoder to get all of the other properties out. I'll give it a shot now and write back.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to play a sound from a certain time instead of from the start. Is that possible in OpenAL?

Comment: The [OpenAL Programming Guide](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Documentation/OpenAL_Programmers_Guide.pdf) (PDF) mentions source properties called `AL_SEC_OFFSET`, `AL_SAMPLE_OFFSET`, and `AL_BYTE_OFFSET`. It looks like it should be possible to implement seeking using those, see the gain or pitch setting in Finch for code samples. I might add the feature to Finch, but can’t promise you when that would be.

Comment: This is what I tried:
http://tinypaste.com/904d9f71
and i get: Failed to start sound, error code a003.

Comment: That looks fine (you’re missing duration, but that should not prevent the sound from playing). Did you initialize Finch? From the OpenAL Guide linked above it looks like `alSourcePlay` may fail if the source is invalid or when there is no current OpenAL context.

Comment: I initialized finch. I think your FISound init would fail otherwise. I double checked that the data is there and it plays back in AVAudioPlayer correctly. Looks like the a003 code is AL_INVALID_VALUE  an invalid value was passed to an OpenAL function

Comment: I’m not sure how the move-to-chat feature works, but I have moved the discussion to a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6043).